# Java exception in Initialize error thread-10

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, android-ndk

I am trying to use a java sound modulation library for android i.e [sonic](http://dev.vinux-project.org/sonic/). I am trying to run its sample android application but it is giving me exception saying  "exception in Initialize error" i cannot figure out the cause. following is the code kindly check.

```
public class SonicTest extends Activity
{
static Sonic sonic;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                      
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void play(View view)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            final EditText speedEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.speed);
            final EditText pitchEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pitch);
            final EditText rateEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rate);
            float speed = Float.parseFloat(speedEdit.getText().toString());
            float pitch = Float.parseFloat(pitchEdit.getText().toString());
            float rate = Float.parseFloat(rateEdit.getText().toString());
            AndroidAudioDevice device = new AndroidAudioDevice(22050, 1);
            byte samples[] = new byte[4096];
            byte modifiedSamples[] = new byte[2048];
            InputStream soundFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.talking);
            int bytesRead;
            Log.i("Hello", "HI");
             sonic = new Sonic(22050, 1);

            if(soundFile != null) {
                sonic.setSpeed(speed);
                sonic.setPitch(pitch);
                sonic.setRate(rate);
                do {
                    try {
                        bytesRead = soundFile.read(samples, 0, samples.length);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(bytesRead > 0) {
                        sonic.putBytes(samples, bytesRead);
                    } else {
                        sonic.flush();
                    }
                    int available = sonic.availableBytes(); 
                    if(available > 0) {
                        if(modifiedSamples.length < available) {
                            modifiedSamples = new byte[available*2];
                        }
                        sonic.receiveBytes(modifiedSamples, available);
                        device.writeSamples(modifiedSamples, available);
                    }
                } while(bytesRead > 0);
                device.flush();
            }
        }
    } ).start();
}}
```

Sonic class:

```
public class Sonic
{
// Sonic is thread-safe, but to have multiple instances of it, we have to
// store a pointer to it's data. We store that here as a long, just in case
// someone wants to port this JNI wapper to a 64-bit JVM.
long sonicID = 0;

// Create a sonic stream.  Return false only if we are out of memory and cannot
// allocate the stream. Set numChannels to 1 for mono, and 2 for stereo.
public Sonic(int sampleRate, int numChannels)
{
    close();
    sonicID = initNative(sampleRate, numChannels);
}

// Call this to clean up memory after you're done processing sound.
public void close()
{
    if(sonicID != 0) {
        closeNative(sonicID);
        sonicID = 0;
    }
}

// Just insure that close gets called, in case the user forgot.
protected void finalize()
{
    // It is safe to call this twice, in case the user already did.
    close();
}

// Force the sonic stream to generate output using whatever data it currently
// has.  No extra delay will be added to the output, but flushing in the middle of
// words could introduce distortion.
public void flush()
{
    flushNative(sonicID);
}

// Set the sample rate of the stream.  This will drop any samples that have not been read.
public void setSampleRate(int newSampleRate)
{
    setSampleRateNative(sonicID, newSampleRate);
}

// Get the sample rate of the stream.
public int getSampleRate()
{
    return getSampleRateNative(sonicID);
}

// Set the number of channels.  This will drop any samples that have not been read.
public void setNumChannels(int newNumChannels)
{
    setNumChannelsNative(sonicID, newNumChannels);
}

// Get the number of channels.
public int getNumChannels()
{
    return getNumChannelsNative(sonicID);
}

// Set the pitch of the stream.
public void setPitch(float newPitch)
{
    setPitchNative(sonicID, newPitch);
}

// Get the pitch of the stream.
public float getPitch()
{
    return getPitchNative(sonicID);
}

//Set the speed of the stream.
public void setSpeed(float newSpeed)
{
    setSpeedNative(sonicID, newSpeed);
}

// Get the speed of the stream.
public float getSpeed()
{
    return getSpeedNative(sonicID);
}

// Set the rate of the stream.  Rate means how fast we play, without pitch correction
// You probably just want to use setSpeed and setPitch instead.
public void setRate(float newRate)
{
    setRateNative(sonicID, newRate);
}

// Get the rate of the stream.
public float getRate()
{
    return getRateNative(sonicID);
}

// Set chord pitch mode on or off.  Default is off.  See the documentation
// page for a description of this feature.
public void setChordPitch(boolean useChordPitch)
{
    setChordPitchNative(sonicID, useChordPitch);
}

// Get the chord pitch setting.
public boolean getChordPitch()
{
    return getChordPitchNative(sonicID);
}

// Use this to write 16-bit data to be speed up or down into the stream.
// Return false if memory realloc failed, otherwise true.
public boolean putBytes(byte[] buffer, int lenBytes)
{
    return putBytesNative(sonicID, buffer, lenBytes);
}

// Use this to read 16-bit data out of the stream.  Sometimes no data will
// be available, and zero is returned, which is not an error condition.
public int receiveBytes(byte[] ret, int lenBytes)
{
    return receiveBytesNative(sonicID, ret, lenBytes);
}

// Return the number of samples in the output buffer
public int availableBytes()
{
    return availableBytesNative(sonicID);
}

// Set the scaling factor of the stream.
public void setVolume(float newVolume)
{
    setVolumeNative(sonicID, newVolume);
}

// Get the scaling factor of the stream.
public float getVolume()
{
    return getVolumeNative(sonicID);
}

private native long initNative(int sampleRate, int channels);
// When done with sound processing, it's best to call this method to clean up memory.
private native void closeNative(long sonicID);
private native void flushNative(long sonicID);
// Note that changing the sample rate or num channels will cause a flush.
private native void setSampleRateNative(long sonicID, int newSampleRate);
private native int getSampleRateNative(long sonicID);
private native void setNumChannelsNative(long sonicID, int newNumChannels);
private native int getNumChannelsNative(long sonicID);
private native void setPitchNative(long sonicID, float newPitch);
private native float getPitchNative(long sonicID);
private native void setSpeedNative(long sonicID, float newSpeed);
private native float getSpeedNative(long sonicID);
private native void setRateNative(long sonicID, float newRate);
private native float getRateNative(long sonicID);
private native void setChordPitchNative(long sonicID, boolean useChordPitch);
private native boolean getChordPitchNative(long sonicID);
private native boolean putBytesNative(long sonicID, byte[] buffer, int lenBytes);
private native int receiveBytesNative(long sonicID, byte[] ret, int lenBytes);
private native int availableBytesNative(long sonicID);
private native void setVolumeNative(long sonicID, float newVolume);
private native float getVolumeNative(long sonicID);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("sonic");
}}
```

and following is my log file.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.vinuxproject.sonic.SonicTest$1.run(SonicTest.java:50)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sonic: findLibrary returned    null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put `libsonic.so` inside the folder `libs/armeabi` of your project

Comment: still getting the same error. I get error at "Sonic sonic = new Sonic(22050, 1);" in sonicTest Class please Help.

Comment: what is the content of the libs/armeabi folder?

Comment: I have android-support-v4.jar, Android.mk, Application.mk, sonic.c , sonic.h, sonicjni.c and sonicjni.h in libs folder.

Comment: Why do you have c and h files inside your libs folder ?

Comment: from where i can get libsonic.so?

Comment: is libsonic a thyrd party library or is a library of yours?

Comment: I used this [link](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk). In the end it says import contents of libs folder to the libs folder of the project.

Comment: No. Did nothing just imported the android project. Please guide me. Have no idea what to do.

Comment: there is to much to say. You are trying to import a project that use native code (Code writen in c/c++). You want to build in order to use  (no prebuild jar) you should prepare your environemnt in order to work with the android NDK. I suggest you to read http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/ and other similar tutoria

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the jar to your build path (you probably already have because it compiles) and also have to check the library on the "Order and Export"-tab under Android in your project settings.

Comment: what jar file. there is not jar file with the source code of sonic-ndk sample app.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was a Java-library. From the sonic site: "There is a simple sonic library in ANSI C, and one in pure Java." Since you said you wanted to use a "java sound modulation library", I thought you'd use the Java version.

Comment: can you give me link to the pure java version of this sonic library?

Comment: From what I read, it's all included in the tarball: "For now, feel free to simply add sonic.c and sonic.h to your application (or Sonic.java)". Seems like you just have to copy Sonic.Java to your project (and add it to build path).

Comment: add what to the build path. Don't have any jar file. just sonic.java.

Comment: The Java file. Either you create a jar yourself and add it to the build path, or you add the java file. Just add the java file to your source folder (you might have to adjust the package name or copy it to the correct location). Then it should automatically be on your build path.